# Phonegap adding items to the notification tray

Tags: android, cordova

I am just learning [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) and I would like to push notifications to the notification tray on a timer.

I tried the [notification function](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html#Notification) in the PhoneGap API but its only for messages boxes with in the application its self.

Any ideas how to send a push notifications to the "Notification tray" android system?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

UPDATE: I have not worked with Phonegap for a very long time, and this repo is no longer managed.

---

Here is a phonegap plugin that I have written for system notifications.

https://github.com/saileshmittal/phonegap-system-notification-plugin

Comment: Works great!, How did you find this question? I see that you are brand new on this site. Welcome.

Comment: Thanks Steven :). And I'll be glad if u include this to your plugin repo fil maj. And its open to any editions as well.

Comment: @ fil mah, So did you still intend to add it to the phonegap plugin repo? Or did that get nixed?

Comment: its included under a different name

Comment: Note this plugin is no longer maintained, check the answer by @bond for a more up-to-date plugin for 2.x. For 3.x (aka Cordova) check the notes on the listed git repo.

Answer (score 6):

Official phonegap plugin contains the status bar notification. You can find how to set it up [here](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/StatusBarNotification):

You can look at all the supported plugins at the [Cordova Plugin Registry](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2013/10/21/cordova-registry.html)

Comment: The repository seems to be deprecated for Phonegap/Cordova 3